# name-value-pair string to Json

Tags: asp.net, json.net

Trying to get an object out of str1=X&str2=Y using Newtonsoft.Json

Getting: "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: s. Line 1, position 1."

Am i way off expecting this to work?

```
public class MyTest 
{
    public string str1 { get; set; }
    public string str2 { get; set; }
}

public MyTest GetJson()
{
        data = "str1=X&str2=Y";
        JsonSerializerSettings jss = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        jss.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;
        jss.ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Reuse;
        MyTest myTest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyTest>(data, jss);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you're way off. json looks more like this:

```
{"str1":"x","str2":"y"}
```

See www.json.org for more information.

## Edit

To convert a query string to json:

```
var queryString = "str1=X&str2=Y";
var queryParams = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);

var jsonObject = new JObject(from k in queryParams.AllKeys 
                             select new JProperty(k, queryParams[k]));
```

To convert a json string to an object:

```
MyTest test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyTest>(jsonObject.ToString());
```

To convert an object to json:

```
var test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( new MyTest{str1 = "X", str2 = "Y"});
```

Comment: One minor nit, proper JSON always encapsulates the key names in double quotes: `{"str1":"x","str2":"y"}` Though this is not always enforced. Your example is a javascript object literal which while similar, is not the same.

Comment: while that's a valid Javascript object, it's not valid JSON.  JSON requires keys to be quoted as well, you'd have this:

`{"str1":"x","str2":"y"}`

Comment: yeah i know that, I am trying to transform the string into json. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

That's a query string, not a JSON string.
You can parse it using [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx), which returns a `NameValueCollection`.

Comment: which leaves me about the same place, how do i convert NameValueCollection into json?